# Need help fetching data from a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

Sorry for this but I'm real new to sqlite: i've created a database from an excel sheet I had, and I can't seem to fetch the values of the column I need

```
query = """ SELECT GNCR from table"""
cur.execute(query)
```

This actually works, but

```
query = """ SELECT ? from table"""
cur.execute(query, my_tuple)
```

doesn't

Here's my code:

```
def print_col(to_print):
    db = sqlite3.connect('my_database.db')
    cur = db.cursor()
    query = " SELECT ? FROM my_table "
    cur.execute(query, to_print)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)
print_col(('GNCR',))
```

The result is:

[('GNCR',), ('GNCR',), ('GNCR',), ('GNCR',), [...]]

instead of the actual values
What's the problem ? I can't figure it out

Comment: Table and column names have to be present in the query when it's compiled; they can't be parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "?" character in query is used for parameter substitution. Sqlite will escape the parameter you passed and replace "?" with the send text. So in effect you query after parameter substitution will be `SELECT 'GNCR' FROM my_table` where GNCR will be treated as text so you will get the text for each row returned by you query instead of the value of that column.

Basically you should use the query parameter where you want to substitute the parameter with escaped string like in where clause. You can't use it for column name.